# Как сделать автоматический фокус на конкретный EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Доброго времени суток колеги, столкнулся с интересной задачкой: имеется layout, на котором размещен pager, который в свою очередь даёт доступ к условным 4 другим фрагментам (page), на каждом из которых в свою очередь размещены условные 2 editText-а, и button(на последнем из фрагментов), который при нажатии сохраняет все 4*2 значения полей.

На данный момент реализована валидация, и если любое из значений пусто, то отображаем сообщения (toast), и не даём возможность сохранить.

**Вопрос**: как сделать фокусировку первого пустого EditText-a. То есть: если у нас из 8-ми editText-ов (id1, id2, .. , id8), id3 и id6 не заполнены, то при нажатии на button выдаст toast о том, что не все поля заполнены, и автоматически перенаправит на page(фрагмент) номер 2 и поставит фокус на EditText с id3?

Возможно ли это сделать? Нужны ваши советы, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вроде как есть параметр и слушатель к нему editText.setOnFocusChangeListener

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то так ты отлавливаешь нажатие пользователя на конкретный editText, а меня интересует программное иммитирование этого нажатия на editText, если оно пустое, и переход на тот фрагмент(page), где находится этот конкретный editText

Comment: editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
               ...
            }
        } про эту конструкцию я вкурсе, но не думаю, что она тут применима

Comment: editText.requestFocus()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077755/edittext-request-focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

или

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, всем спасибо, решено таким способом: на каждый fragment проверка isValid(), если есть незаполненые поля, возвращаем этот фрагмент делаем проверку на каджый editText, если пустые, то editText.requestFocus()